# logging payload of request in wso2am

Tags: wso2-api-manager

with the following mediation i log headers of a request

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="WSO2AM--Ext--In">
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="system_time" expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"/>
        <property name="application" scope="transport" expression="get-property('api.ut.application.name')"/>
        <property name="api name" scope="transport" expression="get-property('api.ut.api')"/>
        <property name="method" scope="transport" expression="get-property('api.ut.HTTP_METHOD')"/>
        <property name="resource" scope="transport" expression="get-property('api.ut.resource')"/>
    </log>
</sequence>
```

but i also want to log payload of request. how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use log level as full and it will log the payload.
. However, this will parse the message content and will have a performance hit.

For more info, please visit [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/mediators/log-mediator/)